# preg_replace and condition inside it?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I use this code to strip all links from text:

$string = preg_replace("/\]*)>([^<]*)\</a>/i", "$2", $string);

But I want somehow don't to strip links that point to some domain, for example google.com
So, I want to remove all other URLs, but to keep link to one domain.

How can I add some condition in preg_replace ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for the condition.

But you'll likely be better off parsing the HTML and manipulating the DOM. The reason is, your regexp will always have some kind of flaws in it. The current one, for instance, wouldn't prevent someone from adding a link like so:

```
<a href=evil><b>foo</b></a >
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me how to use that function, I mean how keep links for one domain ?

Comment: See examples #2 and #3 in the docs, for how to use the function. Use `var_dump()` to look at the input argument: it's an array that contains the capture, much like the `$match` argument from `preg_match()`.

Comment: I got it how to make function and inside function I check if(is domain I want to skip), but how to tell it that in that case need to skip preg_replace and keep original html ?
function parseSdomains($matches){

 $skipURL = 'google.com';

 if(!strpos($matches[1],$skipURL)){
  return $matches[2];
 }
 else{
 WHAT TO SAY HERE ?
 }
 
}